# Google Maps map tiles request issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, nginx, jboss

I'm having a awkward situation with the Google Maps API v3 that is giving me some hard time.

I have a website using jBoss EAP 6.3 that uses the api, no problems with the site, analysis at gtmetrix gives me two A's, no major problems.

I have the same website using nginx only, the api it's used in the same way, the only difference is that this one uses angular.js. This one is the problem, the analysis at gtmetrix points me to two major problems:

[image: First Error]
[image: Second Error]

My question is: why is this happening? Since the logic for the map it's the same on both sites?

Comment: [**same question as last week**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321776/google-maps-tiles-with-no-image-dimensions-and-cache-validator), same comment: **So what's the issue? As long as the ressources(maps-API and images) are not under your control you can't do anything(except of sending a feature-request to google)**

Comment: The issue is why the different behaviour if the logic is the same. The API is the same in both sites, so it isn't the problem.

Comment: Not about programming but I agree with the question. The API TOS say *no caching of content* so I guess Google wouldn't much care about it but as @Dr.Molle said you can submit a feature request. Now why does the servers config impact the analysis, I have no idea. To me it's a simple warning more than a *High priority recommendation*.